# Where do I begin troubleshooting Mysites not working _sometimes_?

Tags: mysites

I have a 2012 farm with Mysites installed and configured. Sometimes clicking "about me" from the top right displays the "Sorry, something went wrong" page, but sometimes it works fine.  When it works fine, sometimes there's a smaller "sorry, something went wrong" halfway down the page where information should be.

All my research and Googling about this, shows people who never had Mysites set up at all, or didn't have the user profile service and service application configured or configured properly, and therefore Mysites *never* works.  How do I commence troubleshooting something that periodically works?  The Windows event viewer?  In a 2 WFE and 2 backend farm, which Windows event viewer shows this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error messages in SharePoint usually come with *Corelation ID*. Use it to find relevant entries in ULS logs.
By default you can find SharePoint logs in 15 hive, under:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS
```

You can use [`Merge-SPLogFile`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607721.aspx) PowerShell cmdlet to gather logs from all servers and [ULS Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020) to open log files.

Comment: Ok this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks very much.  The "message" field gives an indication of where to go next and I'll be able to hunt it down.  Looks like the server is using up its memory, I'll start there.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a resource based issue . Please check your RAM and CPU usage at that time , if you find high CPU and resource utilization upgrade your hardware.